# How can I make text file and put the data(str and int) in python?

Tags: python

I have to extract some text file using python and using db2.

I wanna make like this:
- there are some data in DB.
- using this data, I wanna make text file

eg. in text file:

first line: 111111test(blanks)   22222test(blanks)   333333test

second line: 444444test  555test   666666666666test

I knew, writing text file can only use "str" type, but I need to input both numeric data and str data.
How can I input some data with another data type when make text file?
How can I set the length of each data?

e.g.
"4444444test": 11
      "555test": 7

```
a=123
b=("test")
c = []

c= [a,b]

f = open('file.text','w')

for i in range(2):
    f.write(c[i])

f. close()
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

Comment: replace `f.write(c[i])` with `f.write(str(c[i]))`

Comment: For getting the length you can use `len()`, e.g: `len(str(c[i]))`

Comment: thanks, I already know how to change str type but I have to use numeric type. is there any way to use numeric type?

Comment: thanks, I already know the len function, the thing what I wanna say is that how can I set the length of each element of List before I put the some data